# Make has_many :through not deleteable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using an active flag on my joined model, rather then deleting them. How can I specify a condition that prevents the possibility to destroy these entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you create a new field in your table and name it as is_deleted with data type boolean.And update it instead of destroying the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should override destroy method in your model/models.

Similar solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333524/4416209

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with the [paranoia gem](https://github.com/radar/paranoia). This will use a deleted_at timestamp for a soft delete and add necessary conditions to filter out 'deleted' records.

If you want to keep the active column, you can read the source code for inspiration. Basically it just adds a default scope to any class including it and replaces destroy by:

```
 def destroy
   transaction do
     run_callbacks(:destroy) do
       touch_paranoia_column
     end
   end
 end
```

So insteand of

```
touch_paranoia_column
```

You can use

```
update_attribute(:active, true)
```

Hope this helped you out.